# Ubuntu 17.04 login loop, keyboard unresponsive, nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm, 17.04

I have looked at a few similar questions on this website, but so far none seem to solve my particular issue.  I have recently compiled kernel 4.12 and have opted to use only one processor (for testing purposes).  I was previously using Nvidia graphics drivers.  After the kernel compilation, I was stuck in a login loop -- any time I tried to login, I would see a black screen then be taken back to the login screen.

I tried a fix I found on a similar question that said I should install gdm3 and use that over lightdm, so I did. Then, when booting, my keyboard is unresponsive and I see the following messages:

> nvidia: version magic '4.12.9 SMP mod_unload ' shouuld be '4.12.9 mod_unload'
>
> nvidia: version magic '4.12.9 SMP mod_unload ' shouuld be '4.12.9 mod_unload'
>
> kvm: disabled by bios
>
> Started Run Click sysem-level hooks.
>
> Created slice User Slice of gdm.
>
> Started User Manager for UID 126.
>
> Started Session c1 of user gdm.
>
> Started User Manager for UID 126...
>
> Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
>
> Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
>
> Stopping User Manager for UID 126...

I cannot launch a terminal via ctrl + alt + f3, as my keyboard input is not recognized.

Comment: Most likely proprietary drivers don't support the 4.12 kernel yet.

Comment: And installing a new manager is NOT a solution. In such cases it can only make things worse.

Comment: @MichaelBay I see that.

Comment: @Pilot6 However, I can't swap off of the proprietary drivers now because I am stuck in the perpetual loop.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel.